# Generate infinite sequence in Elixir

Tags: elixir

How can i implement a infinite sequence generator that i can operate on using the `Stream` library functions?

I want to use that to generate the first n prime numbers. I have a working recursive approach, but i like enumerables and pipes a lot better.

I have seen this done in python using a generator:

```
def number_generator():
  n = 3
  while True:
    yield n
    n += 2
```

Is there a built-in function to generate such sequences in Elixir, or a easy DIY alternative? Does this pattern have a name in Elixir?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have at least two options to generate a stream in Elixir. The most generic is `Stream.unfold`

```
Stream.unfold(3, fn(x) -> {x, x + 2} end)

# or

Stream.unfold(3, &({&1, &1 + 2}))
```

but in your case you can use the simpler `Stream.iterate`

```
Stream.iterate(3, fn(x) -> x + 2 end)

# or

Stream.iterate(3, &(&1 + 2))
```

Comment: Now how would I implement the idea of Python's `next()` which gets the next item in the stream?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne there's no such thing in Elixir. Stream generator functions may have side effects (such as advancing a pointer in a file stream) and so you must consume a stream by enumerating it with `Enum.reduce` or  another function from the `Enum` module. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Usually it just requires a slightly different way of thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 5):

[`Stream.iterate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#iterate/2) comes to the rescue:

```
generator = Stream.iterate(3, &(&1+2))
#⇒ #Function<61.8243704/2 in Stream.unfold/2>
generator |> Enum.take(5)
#⇒ [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```